# How can I create bots that will download CSV?

Tags: library, php, automation

So I wanted to automate some of my work, my daily task includes logging to different websites and download the CSV by selecting some dimensions, metrics and date range.

So is there any open source technology available that I can use to automate all my tasks? Also, I want to do it without web scraping.

FYI: There's no API available for the data downloading.

Comment: Can you code? Python would be ideal

Comment: I am a coder. But python is new for me JS and PHP are my niche languages

Comment: Hmmm,  Selenium is the best thing there is for automating browser tasks.  Take a look at that.

Comment: On Windows, learn about the task scheduler and its predecessor, the `at`demon. On linux, learn what the `cron` demon and a crontab are.

Comment: isn't there any open source library available? or any bot?

Comment: @Mawg what do you guys think of selenium?

Comment: I have only used it lightly, but a friend of mine who is a recruiter, not a programmer, knocked up a script in an afternoon, so you will not find it difficult. It is the industry standard for testing browsers & browser apps, so has lots of support.

Comment: Feel free to upvote my comments :-) Seriously, that will help others who read this future. What will also help is if you post an answer and accept it. It's not about the points; those upvotes & accepted answers are helpful indicators to those who read questions later